# pymysql times out in lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda, pymysql

I'm trying to connect to a database using pymysql.  Using the following, with the actual credentials.

```
mydb = pymysql.connect(host=host, user=user, passwd=password, db=databasename)
```

When I run the script on my machine it connect without an issue.

But when I upload and test in my lambda function i get the following error, even though its using the same exact credentials:

```
  "errorType": "OperationalError",
  "errorMessage": "(2003, \"Can't connect to MySQL server on 'host' (timed out)\")"
```

Comment: 1. Check that your lambda has access to the server. 2. Increase the timeout threshold.

Comment: Where do I check #1? 

#2 the thresh hold is 20 sec, and its timing it self out after 10 so that should be okay.

Comment: Is your server running in a VPC? Does the lambda has access to the VPC? Are there any networking issues between them?